# Is there an easier way to solve this problem?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, analysis

[image: Pandas dataframe]

I have a pandas dataframe with three columns. The data was messy but I've cleaned it up till this point. II want to assign a tier rating to each organisation but as you can see, the tier can have two or in some cases three rows-worth of cells.

At the moment I'm trying to write a for-loop by first creating a list from the Tier Rating column and then using df.iterrows to go through the list and combine the multiple cells into one cell..

It's getting pretty complicated and from experience this usually means there's an easier way to do it. This is my first time asking a question so I apologize if its long-winded and complicated. Please let me know if I can clear anything up.

Thank you!

Comment: Please include **text** representation of your source data.
We have no time to rewrite your data from a picture.

Comment: Include code of what you have attempted so far.

Comment: Post data and expected outcome, but cant you just use .split() on the Tier column and lambda function to pull out individual tiers